# Docker: link between client and server

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I'm running a simple spring microservice project with Docker. I have two projects: lucky-word-client (on port 8080) and lucky-word-server (on port 8001). But I can't communicate client with server. Infact if lucky-word-client communicates with lucky-word-server, the result is the word "Evviva", else the word is "Default". My result is always "Default", but I want communicate client with server to have the word "Evviva".

This is two classes of lucky-word-client:

```
package asw.springcloud.luckyword;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LuckyWordApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LuckyWordApplication.class, args);
    }
}


package asw.springcloud.luckyword;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@RestController
public class LuckyWordController {

    @Value("${lucky-word}") 
    private String luckyWord;

    @RequestMapping("/lucky-word")
    public String luckyWord() {
        return "The lucky word is: " + luckyWord; 
    }
}
```

This is the file application.properties of lucky-word-client:

```
# application.properties 
# parola fortunata di default (if server is not accessible)
lucky-word=Default
```

This is the file bootstrap.properties of lucky-word-client:

```
 # bootstrap.properties 
    spring.application.name=lucky-word 
    # i profili possibili sono italian e english
    spring.profiles.active=italian 
    # oppure: export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=italian 
    spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8001
```

This is the file Dockerfile of lucky-word-client:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8 

ADD build/libs/lucky-word-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar lucky-word-client.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-Xmx128m", "-Xms128m"]

CMD ["-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=italian", "lucky-word-client.jar"]
```

This is the class of lucky-word-server:

```
package asw.springcloud.configserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class CommonConfigServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CommonConfigServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the file application.properties of lucky-word-server:

```
# application.yml 
---
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/..../
          searchPaths: projects/config-data
server:
  port: 8001
```

This is the file Dockerfile of lucky-word-server:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8 

ADD build/libs/common-config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar common-config-server.jar

EXPOSE 8001

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-Xmx128m", "-Xms128m"]

CMD ["-jar", "common-config-server.jar"]
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48360582/2597143

Answer (score 2):

I assume that this config line from your client is expected to point to your server:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8001
```

However if both your client and your server are deployed as docker containers, localhost won't work.

For a running docker container localhost is pointing to itself, the container, and not the host on which the container runs. It is not related to Spring but purely to docker networking.

See: https://docs.docker.com/network/

Basically you would need to deploy both containers in the same network and use the container name as a host.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the network/host mode you use while running your containers. Using `--network host`, enables network host mode, which would enable you using `localhost`. Check [this manual](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/).

Another option could be setting it up similar to this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  client:
    build: <PATH TO DOCKERFILE>
    ports:
      - "8080"
    networks:
      - general
  server:
    build: <PATH TO DOCKERFILE>
    ports:
      - "8001"
    networks:
      - general

networks:
  general:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

Afterwards your containers would be on the same network and could connect via: `<CONTAINER_NAME>:PORT`, e.g. client connects to `server:8001`